# Reading array of objects in React returns an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/book-list-forked-ni8iz) there's a `books.js` file with an array of objects that is exported and then imported in `components/BookList.js`. I assumed `books` would be imported as-is (an array of objects), but it actually turned out to be an object. Thus, the author used `const bookList = Object.values(books)` to get an array that could be iterated with `map`.

Why wasn't `books` an array after being imported? Is there anything wrong with either the content of `books.js`, the way it is being imported in `BookList.js`, or perhaps that is how it is supposed to be?

Comment: It is being imported as an array of objects. `Object.values(books)` will give you the same array. It is not needed at all.

Comment: In the example, the use of `Object.values` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you! I was surprised to see that as well, so I put a console.log to see the type and I am confident I saw an object instead of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an array, it is just how codesandbox you've used makes it look like an object.

```
import React from "react";
import Book from "./Book";
import { books } from "../books";

const BookList = () => {
  return (
    <section>
      {books.map((book) => (
        <article key={`${book.title}.toLowerCase().split(" ").join("-")}`}>
          <Book
            title={book.title}
            author={book.author}
            image={book.imageLink}
            altText={book.title}
          />
        </article>
      ))}
    </section>
  );
};

export default BookList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `const bookList = Object.values(books);` and iterate `bookList` with `.map()`, you should do `books.map()`.